# How can I use a listview item as a button in uwp app? or how can I change text of a textbox by clicking on a listview item in uwp?

Tags: object, listview, uwp, click, listviewitem

```
private void lstvActiveIssues_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Issue issue = (Issue)lstvActiveIssues.SelectedItem;
        tbxTest.Text = issue.Description;
    }
```

**the issue is null here. It means that the item is not selected. **

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvActiveIssues" Header="Active documents" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10" Background="#FF1F2436" ItemClick="lstvActiveIssues_ItemClick" IsItemClickEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Issue">                        
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10">
                                <TextBlock Text="Customer Id:" Margin="10" />
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Customer.Id}" Margin="10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                 
                                <TextBlock Text="Customer Name:" Margin="10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Customer.FirstName}" Margin="10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Customer.LastName}" Margin="10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>                                              
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

> //I have added the xaml code here.

Comment: Hello, if you can show the corresponding XAML code, it will be helpful for us to analyze your problem.

Comment: Hello, I have updated the code above. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ItemClickEventArgs` has a `ClickedItem` property that gets a reference to the clicked item:

```
private void lstvActiveIssues_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Issue issue = e.ClickedItem as Issue;
    tbxTest.Text = issue?.Description;
}
```